# Bind live change listener to a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table in which one column contains a select box.
I need to bind a listener to any select activity so as to change some properties of my table row based on which row's select box has been changed. So as its apparent I do not have a fix id for a select box.
Following is the code that I was trying but it is not working. More rows maybe added to the table in the future so a live listener is necessary.

```
$('#datatable').on('change', '.MediaType  select' function(){
    console.log('Changed');
    //console.log($(this.find('select :selected').text()));
});
```

Here MediaType is the class of the enclosing td element. 'datatable' is my table's id.
Could somebody please suggest a solution.

**Corrected Version Is Below:**

```
$('#datatable').on('change', '.MediaType  select' function(){
console.log('Changed');
    //Below line to get value of selected
console.log($(this, ':selected').val()));

});
```

Comment: First of all remove the comma "," in `'.MediaType , select'` comma means OR.

Comment: @mohkhan and what's wrong with that ? he might want to listen to them both

Comment: @RoyiNamir the OP said enclosing td

Comment: MediaType is a TD and he mentions that MediaType encloses the select and as per his intentions the event shuld be bound on the select and not td.

Comment: I did that only before I copied my changed code by mistake.

Comment: There is one comma missing between `'.MediaType select'` and `function()`, is that copying mistake too?

Comment: No that was the mistake I found that out myself it seems. Dumb me :(
See my comment below in pxL's answer

Comment: In your browser console can you try `$('#datatable .MediaType select').length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As .MediaType is td  containing the span, you want to bind change event to span and not to the td

You can remove that `,`

```
$('#datatable').on('change', '.MediaType select'
```

to get the selected value :

`$(this).val();`

Comment: I don't think it is OP's issue here, as change event bubbles, you could still bound it to TD: jsfiddle.net/97VCA

Comment: I found my error. There is no comma between the 'select' and the function.

Comment: @pXL could you tell me how to get the value of selected option from here.
I tried $('this :selected').text()
Didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure `#datatable` is in DOM at time you try to set handler:

```
$(function () { // DOM ready handler
    $('#datatable').on('change', '.MediaType  select', function () {
        console.log('Changed');
    });
});
```

If datatable is a dynamic element too, use as delegate target the closest static container, here as i don't know your HTML, i'm using document object:

```
 $(document).on('change', '#datatable .MediaType  select', function () {
     console.log('Changed');
 });
```